# Adding file names in a folder to DropDownList. (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

I tried add the names of files in a folder to one dropdownlist. With this code, the path of the files appears. I  tried something to make only the file names appear, but they looked vertical in dropdownlist.

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles("d:\\a\\b\\c\\", "*.jpg");
 ddChoose.DataSource = files;
 ddChoose.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\temp\11\", "*.jpg")
            .Select(fullName=>System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullName));

        ddChoose.DataSource = files;
        ddChoose.DataBind();
    }

//  private string purgePath(string fullName)
//  {
//      var index = fullName.LastIndexOf('\\');
//      return fullName.Substring(index + 1);
//  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\temp\", "*.jpg");
        IEnumerable<string> data = files.Select(purgePath);

        ddChoose.DataSource = data;
        ddChoose.DataBind();
    }

    private string purgePath(string fullName)
    {
        var index = fullName.LastIndexOf('\\');
        return fullName.Substring(index + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. So how can I delete the extensions at the end of the name?

Comment: hi @Allen to do it the standard way, you can isolate a filename with **Path.GetFileName()** and remove the extension using **Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()**

Comment: to @Goodies , yes, Path class do better job, thanks.